# ASM Bytecode - Get line numbers from label offset

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

Is there a way to get line numbers (as in the java file) from the label offset?

```
  @Override
  public void visitLabel(Label label){
    super.visitLabel(label);
    mv.visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out",
        "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
    mv.visitLdcInsn("line " + label.getOffset() + " executed");
    mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println",
        "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
  }
```

I have overwritten the visitLabel method in the MethodVisitor to print the lebel.getOffset when it visits each label. I get some integer values but they are not same as the line numbers in the java file.

Comment: They should be otherwise debugging wouldn't work (which is what they are used for)

Comment: Can you suggest how to extract the line number from the label offset? TIA

Comment: there should be a line number if you compiled it with debugging information.

Comment: As [the documentation of `getOffset()`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/Label.html#getOffset--) states, it’s the byte code offset within the method, so yes, you will get same integer values, but not line numbers. You could have saved some time by reading the documentation instead of trying out…

Comment: I did read but I was wondering if there was a way to map those offsets to line numbers. But there isn't. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a custom mapping. Every line number is visited with reference to a label and every label is visited in the order of their occurance. You would need to:

1. Remember every label that references a line number.
2. Check for any label which line number was the most recent previous to a label being visited.

Comment: Unfortunately, it’s not that easy. ASM may create multiple labels for a single code location and the line number is not enforced to be visited before all other labels of the same position. So the most recently visited line number might be way out of date, compared to the one that might be visited right after `visitLabel`. Since you can’t know in advance, whether a `visitLineNumber` call will follow directly after your current `visitLabel`, I see no single-pass solution…